# How to convert key byte array to string and vice versa

Tags: java, string, byte, arrays, type-conversion

I am generating two keys: 1) Public key and 2) Private key, both are stored as byte array,
I need to convert these two keys into string and send it to receiver side and receiver will convert string to byte array. But somehow it gives different key bytes after converting string to byte array

coding:

```
 System.out.println("certificate insertionSuccessful."+certPojo.getUser_public_key()+", "+certPojo.getUser_private_key());

String str1 = new String(certPojo.getUser_public_key());
String str2 = new String(certPojo.getUser_private_key());

System.out.println("publickey===>"+str1);
System.out.println("privatekey===>"+str2);

byte[] bytes1 = str1.getBytes();
byte[] bytes2 = str2.getBytes();

System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes1);
System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes2);

I also tried using UTF-8 but nothing works
```

output :

[image]

Comment: How do you compare byte arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Writing strings with arbitrary bytes invokes the default character encoding.  Since some byte sequences cannot be represented in the encoding as characters, they'll get lost in the conversion.  I would recommend encoding the bytes in Base64 if you need them converted to a string.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html

Comment: This works, is there anything you're doing differently?

   `@Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        byte[] in = new byte[]{0,0,2,3,4,6,0x0e,0x0c,1,7,8,9};
        String asString = Base64.encodeBase64String(in);
        byte[] out = Base64.decodeBase64(asString);
        assertArrayEquals(out, in);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here...

```
String str1 = new String(certPojo.getUser_public_key());
String str2 = new String(certPojo.getUser_private_key());
```

You are converting string from byte[].. it will add some extra character... so its batter to transfer this kind of information as byte[] itself.. or you can try base64 for encoding and decoding keys... it may help.

Answer (score 0):

`byte[]` (or any other arrays) don't have an overriden toString, so what they show you is just the object identifier itself. Therefore, two different arrays will never show the same string representation.

To print the array contents proper, use `Arrays.toString()`